# "normal" SF stylesheet for customer/partner portal

Tags: customer-portal, css, partner-portal

I like the way salesforce looks for internal users.  The portals look kind of old.

If our partner portal is using all basic SF tabs and visualforce components like listviews, how would we go about including the standard stylesheets on the portal?

I know that you're not supposed to use standard stylesheets for custom dev and sites, but what about the portals...I'd be happy if they were to keep up with SF UI.

Comment: While not a answer, you may find some useful information in [Using Salesforce Styles](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_styling_salesforce.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portal uses the 'old' Salesforce styling still unfortunately. You can use Javascript and some CSS to change how it looks, but it's an unsupported approach and could cause you issues down the line if things don't work as planned.

Your best option might be just to implement custom pages over sites using portal authentication and then you can style them how you want — of course this is a lot more work but it's also not likely to get broken with a seasonal release.